# Adding two items to a list in list commprehension

Tags: python-3.x, list, function, for-loop, list-comprehension

I wrote a for loop which adds the letters of the input into the list "words" and it also adds a space and then the letter if the letter is capital. Like so:

```
def solution(s):
    word = []
    for letter in s:
        print(letter.isupper())
        if letter.isupper():
            word.append(" ")
            word.append(letter)
        else:
            word.append(letter)
    return ''.join(word)

print(solution("helloWorld"))
```

output: hello World

I want to convert this to a list comprehension but it wont take both items I would like to add to the list, I tried the following:

```
def solution(s):
    word = [" " and letter if letter.isupper() else letter for letter in s]
    return ''.join(word)

print(solution("helloWorld"))
```

output: helloWorld

wanted output: hello World

How can I add the space along with the letter if it is an upper case, as done in the for loop?

EDIT:

Found out it can be  done the following way.

```
def solution(s):
    word = [" " + letter if letter.isupper() else letter for letter in s]
    return ''.join(word)
```

Comment: Why do you want it to be list comprehension? not every for loop can or shouldb e converted to a list comprehension, there will be some cases where its not appropriate or makes the code much more complex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code works:

```py
def solution(s):
    word = [f" {letter}" if letter.isupper() else letter for letter in s]
    return ''.join(word)

print(solution("helloWorldFooBar"))
```

result: `hello World Foo Bar`

Comment: Yep this also  did the trick. I managed to also solve it with the edit on the post.